# Is there a browser event when a drag operation is cancelled via the Escape key?

Tags: javascript, browser, drag-and-drop

I need to undo the drag-drop preview when a drag operation is cancelled. Need to do this in all cases, when cancelling is done via the Escape key or just by removing the mouse button. I do not want to track keyup and mouseup events but would prefer a event that just reports cancellation of the drag operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dragend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragend_event)

> The dragend event is fired when a drag operation is being ended (by releasing a mouse button or hitting the escape key).

Comment: I tried exactly that but it did not work. But as I see there is a problem with my event binding, you are right, thx.